# Testing Custom Route Model Binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to test a custom class that implements `\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlRoutable` and can't get the `resolveRouteBinding` method invoked.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Tests\TestCase;

class BindingExampleClassTest extends TestCase
{
    function test_invoke_resolve_route_binding_method()
    {
        Route::get('/invoke-route-binding/{binding}', function (BindingExampleClass $binding) {
            dd($binding);
        });

        $this->get('/invoke-route-binding/1');
    }
}

class BindingExampleClass implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlRoutable
{
    public $id;

    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        $this->id = $value;
    }

    public function getRouteKey()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getRouteKey() method.
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getRouteKeyName() method.
    }

    public function resolveChildRouteBinding($childType, $value, $field)
    {
        // TODO: Implement resolveChildRouteBinding() method.
    }
}
```

The `dd` response is `BindingExampleClass` with `id` still null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering route inside a test function will not include any middleware. When working with route model binding in Laravel, `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` middleware must be defined in the router instance.

```
Route::get('/invoke-route-binding/{binding}', function (BindingExampleClass $binding) {
    dd($binding);
})->middleware(\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class);
```